# Consulta SQL para o retorno da data

Tags: mysql

Nao estou conseguindo resolver esse exercicio de BD.

Pede para usar a funcao data do sql. Temos a data em formato dia/mes/ano, temos que extrair o mes. Temos a tabela vendedor contendo codvend, nomevend e dt_nasc.

Pergunta: Listar todos os vendedores que fazem aniversário entre janeiro e junho retornando o nome do mês.

Porfavor se alguem puder me ajudar, ficarei muito grata.
Obrigada.

Comment: Olá Marilia, e bem vinda do [pt.so]. A dinâmica da comunidade é um pouco diferente, recomendo que faça um passeio pelo [tour], [help] e principalmente [ask]. Poste mais informações, suas tentativas e mostre o esforço que fez antes de trazer a pergunta.

Comment: Qual o formato das suas tabelas?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html Use functions de date e time para isto.

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer mais pesquisa.

Answer (score 2):

Listar todos os vendedores que fazem aniversário entre janeiro e junho retornando o nome do mês. (Edite o nome da tabela e do campo de acordo com sua tabela atual)

```
SELECT id_vendedor, nome_vendedor, MONTHNAME(dt_nascimento) as MesAniversario 
FROM vendedor WHERE MONTH(dt_nascimento) BETWEEN 1 AND 6;
```

Referência: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html